# Android Bluetooth print invoice is not working correctly

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
            Thread mThread = new Thread() {
                public void run(){
                    Looper.prepare();
                    try{
                        if(findBT()){
                            if(openBT()){
                                sendPrintData(printStr.toString());
                                //closeBT();
                                handler.sendEmptyMessage(12);
                            }else{
                                handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);                                                       
                            }
                        }else{
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(11);                       
                        }
                        //endPreparations();
                        //FileHandler.zapInvoiceRecords(getApplicationContext());
                    }catch(IOException ioex){
                        ioex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }                   
            };
            mThread.start();
            Looper.loop();
```

But if invoice is long print is not print all.Can you way to do this?
Printer not working all required data.

Answer (score 0):

If long print (long string) is not printed by the code that means,

- there might be some restrictions on char stream to be sent to the printer **OR**
- bluetooth printer can't receive the data that fast leading to drop the data

To solve these type of problems send data in chunks(break the original string into several strings and use while loop to send those). Keep those chunks of 256 or less characters. Or may be the size which printer is printing properly.